# Abstract class Implementation in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Let me start with the snippet describing my question.

```
class MovableObject : protected BaseObject
{
    protected:
        virtual void move() = 0;
};

class Player : public MovableOject {}

void Player::move() {}
```

When trying to compile the code above I am receiving an error saying that there is no definition of `move` in `Player` class. Only after including declaration of the `move` method to the class declaration I can successfully compile the file. I would expect my children class to have the required declarations but apparently I do have to declare them again. Could anyone explain my why?

Comment: For one thing, the compiler needs to be able to tell whether a given class is abstract or not (meaning, has at least one pure virtual function) by looking at the class definition alone. If it were possible to implement `Player::move` in the source file without first declaring it in the class (typically located in a separate header), then any other source file that includes just the header wouldn't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: put the move function inside the class block

Comment: @Kiashan Kumar, but that is not what I wanted to do.. That is why I had asked the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a declaration of the function before you try to define it outside the class.

```
class Player : public MovableObject
{
    void move() override;    
};
```

Comment: The OP appears to know as much. The question is, and I quote, "Could anyone explain why?"

Comment: I thought that when deriving from a base class the declarations are explicitly included in the child class.

Comment: @mic4ael They are, but all of the derived classes are simply inheriting `MoveableObject::move`, there is no notion of `Player::move` until you tell the compiler that this derived class is going to `override` the `virtual` method.

Comment: Ok, thanks @CoryKramer. That explanation has made things clear now.